# Prove $( q\land((\lnot p \land q) \rightarrow (r \land p))) \Rightarrow p $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I need to prove this using a truth table. I understand the majority of the truth table until it gets to proving  $( q\land((\lnot p \land q) \rightarrow (r \land p))) $ in which I am confused by how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can think about this in English.

It is saying: if q occurs and (q occuring and p not occuring implies that p and r occur), then p must occur.

Let's break this down. First, notice that the statement

(q occuring and p not occuring implies that p and r occur)

is always false, because if p does not occur, that cannot imply that p occurs.

So for the entire statement to be true, the statement (q occuring and p not occuring) must always evaluate to false, because otherwise the clearly incorrect statement 
(q occuring and p not occuring implies that p and r occur) would be true.

Therefore if q occurs, p must also occur.

Answer (score 0):

Well do the column for $\lnot p$ first and then the column for $q$ and then $(\lnot p \land q)$ and then finally $( q\land((\lnot p \land q))$.  Then you do the column for $r$ and then $p$ and finally $(r\land p)$.  Now compare the $( q\land((\lnot p \land q)$ and $(r \land p)$ columns.  The key is to do it step by step. I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

\begin{array}{ccc|cccccccccccccccc}
p&q&r&(& q & \land &((& \neg & p & \land & q & ) & \rightarrow & (& r & \land & p &))) & \rightarrow & p\\
\hline
T&T&T&&T&T&&F&T&F&T&&T&&T&T&T&&T&T\\
T&T&F&&T&T&&F&T&F&T&&T&&F&F&T&&T&T\\
T&F&T&&F&F&&F&T&F&F&&T&&T&T&T&&T&T\\
T&F&F&&F&F&&F&T&F&F&&T&&F&F&T&&T&T\\
F&T&T&&T&F&&T&F&T&T&&F&&T&F&F&&T&F\\
F&T&F&&T&F&&T&F&T&T&&F&&F&F&F&&T&F\\
F&F&T&&F&F&&T&F&F&F&&T&&T&F&F&&T&F\\
F&F&F&&F&F&&T&F&F&F&&T&&F&F&F&&T&F\\
\end{array}